# How can I resolve the error of prebuilt library of Android NDK?

Tags: android, android-ndk, cross-compiling

I am a novice,and I want to study how to build cytology c source codes and run it in Android. I did the following:

1. Download Android SDK and NDK, then set environment in /etc/profile like:

   ```
   ANDROID_SDK_HOME=/home/liuzheli/soft/android-studio
   ANDROID_NDK_HOME=/home/liuzheli/soft/android-ndk-r8e
   PATH=$ANDROID_NDK_HOME:$ANDROID_NDK_HOME/build/tools:$ANDROID_SDK_HOME/bin:$ANDROID_SDK_HOME/sdk/tools:$ANDROID_SDK_HOME/sdk/platform-tools:$PATH
   export  ANDROID_SDK_HOME ANDROID_NDK_HOME PATH
   ```
2. Install NDK

   ```
   make-standalone-toolchain.sh --platform=android-9 --install-dir=/usr/local/my-android-toolchain
   ```
3. Edit `/etc/profile` like:

   ```
   PATH=$ANDROID_NDK_HOME:$ANDROID_NDK_HOME/build/tools:$ANDROID_SDK_HOME/bin:$ANDROID_SDK_HOME/sdk/tools:$ANDROID_SDK_HOME/sdk/platform-tools:/usr/local/my-android-toolchain/bin:$PATH
   export  JAVA_HOME ANDROID_SDK_HOME ANDROID_NDK_HOME CLASSPATH PATH 

   export CC=arm-linux-androideabi-gcc  
   export CXX=arm-linux-androideabi-g++
   ```
4. Cross compile my `gmp-5.0` library. It depends on m4-1.4.13, and I compile it using such commands:

   1. `sudo configure --host=arm-linux-androideabi`
   2. `sudo make`
   3. `sudo make intall`

   The above three steps are all worked correctly.
   And then compile the `gmp` library correctly using the same commands.
5. however, when to use the generated libgmp.so, I meet error:
   In my Android.mk, like :

   ```
   include $(CLEAR_VARS)
   LOCAL_MODULE := libgmp
   LOCAL_SRC_FILES := libgmp.so
   LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDES := /usr/local/include
   include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)
   ```

   When to execute 'ndk-build' command, it shows that:

   ```
   Install        : libgmp.so => libs/armeabi/libgmp.so
   /home/liuzheli/soft/android-ndk-r8e/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/linux-x86/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-strip: Unable to recognise
   ```

   the format of the input file `./libs/armeabi/libgmp.so`

How can I resolve this problem? What is wrong about my operations?

Comment: what is the output of `file ./libs/armeabi/libgmp.so` ?